# DropdownList without a name attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a form in my project, but because I'm using AJAX to post the form values and multiple instances of a certain dropdown (`class` attribute instead of `id`), I'm not in need of a `name` attribute on my form controls.

Is there a way to create a dropdown list dynamically but explicitly omitting the name attribute without getting an exception?

```
@Html.DropDownList(string.Empty, Model, new { @class = "year" })
```

Gives me this exception:

> Value cannot be null or empty.
>     Parameter name: name

because first argument is empty.

Comment: In a case like this you would have to create your own custom HtmlHelperExtenion

Comment: did you find any proper solution? I also need to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like following.

```
@Html.DropDownList("aName", Model, new { Name=string.Empty, @class = "year" })
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I also added id=string.Empty because I wanted no id either.  Note that "Name" is case-sensitive.  "name" will not work.